# Google Visualization X Axis is overlapped

Tags: google-visualization

I am drawing Charts Using google.visualization API .

The User can select a value from DropDown in Front End and clicks on Go , it fetches data from backend .

Sometimes the data that fetched is more and sometimes less

When the Data is more , the x-axis being overlapped

Please see this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/7wYP2/462/

This is my code

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});

function drawVisualization() {
    // Create and populate the data table.
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([["strike_pr","CE","PE"],["5500",1875,2025],["6000",61500,104775],["6100",450,13725],["6500",35400,421800],["6600",150,121950],["6700",600,770925],["6800",13650,370425],["6900",33375,586650],["7000",744375,1122075],["7100",229200,355875],["7200",199800,689850],["7300",461550,244425],["7400",442950,439125],["7500",835350,484725],["7600",459000,82800],["7700",482250,48000],["7800",893250,11550],["7900",1215600,13500],["8000",741150,93525],["8100",242325,6150],["8200",326175,1500],["8300",365850,75],["8500",104850,2925],["9000",13050,11775]]);


    var options = {
        title:"OPTION INDEX distribution",
        width: 800,
        height: 400,
        bar: {groupWidth: "95%"},
        legend: { position: "none" },
        is3D:true,
        "vAxis":{"title":"Open Interest"},
        "hAxis":{"title":"Strike Price"},


      };


    // Create and draw the visualization.
    new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
    draw(data, options);
}

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
```

Could you please let me know how to resolve this issue ??

Comment: try `hAxis.maxAlternation: 1` in your options. -- or `hAxis.slantedText: true` with `hAxis.slantedTextAngle` -- from --> [configuration options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#configuration-options)